# WebRTC ICE connection stuck on checking state

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video-streaming, webrtc

So I'm trying to stream video from a server to client, however establishing an ICE connection is rather erratical at the moment. Half of the time it connects successfully whereas the other half it stays stuck in the `checking` state.

Going through the logs I see that the `Request Received` is at 0 when it gets stuck.

Does anyone have probable causes as to why this is happening?

I've included failed dump below.

[ICE connection stuck on checking state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vr8I.png)

Comment: Please not not post pictures of errors. Post the text. Pictures are not searchable.

Comment: You likely have a bug in your negotiation code. If you include it, we may find it.

Comment: @gperiotto did you ever resolve this?